# Breadcrumbs in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, breadcrumbs

I'm slightly insecure about my breadcrumb solution. Names and links are defined in each controller action:

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/">Home</a>
<% if defined? @l1_link %>
  > <a href="<%= @l1_link%>"><%= @l1_name %></a>
  <% if defined? @l2_link %>
    > <a href="<%= @l2_link%>"><%= @l2_name %></a>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This way I can use:

```
@l1_link = user_path()
```

Question: As I am not that smart - could this kind of system lead to desaster somewhere down the road? Is this (grossly) inefficient?

Comment: Here are two approaches: [Split the URL and display it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555669/easy-breadcrumbs-for-restful-rails-application) A more flexible solution implemented in the controller where you setup the breadcrumbs in the controller: [Easy and Flexible Breadcrumbs for Rails](http://szeryf.wordpress.com/2008/06/13/easy-and-flexible-breadcrumbs-for-rails/)

Comment: Hi,

thanks for the answers
@Simone - I like your solution, never thought about DRY-ing by moving the definition before my actions. I'll take that right away.
@Lolindrath - Yes, the split is nice, however my app is not clean enough (and names change, and i18n etc...)
@Christopher: Got to check the episode, didn't get remark 3. (why full-blown objects?), but Nr. 2 is definitely something I need to think about. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is mostly a matter of opinion, but anyway:

1. I would not want that much logic in a view. We've probably all done it, but it gets messy quickly.
2. The code is not safe against future changes that affect the depth of the tree.
3. Instead of linked variables `*_name` and `*_link`, I'd suggest using proper objects anyway, with some `link_to` functionality.

You might find [Episode 162 of Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/162-tree-based-navigation) of interest for a nice solution that gets by with

```
<% for page in @page.ancestors.reverse %>
  <%= link_to h(page.name), page %> &gt;
<% end %>
```

Comment: That rails cast has been updated. [#162 Tree-Based Navigation (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/162-tree-based-navigation-revised)

Answer (score 32):

Breadcrumbs menu are a recurrent pattern in most Rails applications. To solve this issue, I created and released a plugin called [breadcrumbs_on_rails](http://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails).

You define your breadcrumbs in the controller

```
class MyController

  add_breadcrumb "home", root_path
  add_breadcrumb "my", my_path

  def index
    # ...

    add_breadcrumb "index", index_path
  end

end
```

and you render them in your view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>untitled</title>
</head>

<body>
  <%= render_breadcrumbs %>
</body>
</html>
```

Even if you don't want to use a plugin, I encourage you to give it a look. It's open source and you can grab some idea for your app.

Comment: This is good, but breadcrumbs seem like a view responsibility instead of a controller responsibility. I'd recommend moving the add_breadcrumb method call to your view.

Comment: You can call the method in your controller as well in your view. The controller allows you to define a per-controller navigation level to reduce code duplication in your views.

Answer (score 14):

I made a gem named [Gretel](https://github.com/lassebunk/gretel) that is a Ruby on Rails plugin for creating breadcrumbs. The breadcrumbs are configured in a separate configuration file and selected in the view.

Example `config/breadcrumbs.rb`:

```
crumb :root do
  link "Home", root_path
end

crumb :projects do
  link "Projects", projects_path
end

crumb :project do |project|
  link project.name, project_path(project)
  parent :projects
end

crumb :project_issues do |project|
  link "Issues", project_issues_path(project)
  parent :project, project
end

crumb :issue do |issue|
  link issue.name, issue_path(issue)
  parent :project_issues, issue.project
end
```

In your view:

```
<% breadcrumb :issue, @issue %>
```

In your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<%= breadcrumbs pretext: "You are here: " %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the gem, just tried to add it and I get this "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)". Any help would be appreciated! Best, Alex

Answer (score 5):

Do not use any plugins just for breadcrumbs. This link provides an efficient method to generate breadcrumbs.

http://szeryf.wordpress.com/2008/06/13/easy-and-flexible-breadcrumbs-for-rails/

Although, it is a very old post, it still works.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Ariane http://github.com/simonc/ariane

With it you can generate any kind of breadcrumb, as links in a paragraph or as a ul/li :)

If you want something specific, you can create your own renderer.

It's pretty simple to use, just add this in a `before_filter`:

```
ariane.add 'Home', root_path # in the app controller to have it everywhere
ariane.add 'Some Page', some_path
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a fork of `crumble` gem. It has very few configuration options and it appears abandoned, but when I tried to switch to `breadcrumbs_on_rails` or `gretel`, I realized that I have to add many lines to my views or controllers (and I have a lot of them), but with `crumble` it is all stored in one configuration file. If you like to do some patches and prefer configuration in one place, I think it is the best solution ever.